# How come I can't get logged in user's bearer token to verify auth using Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I have two completely separate code bases:  React.js on the frontend and Laravel on the backend

I'm trying to verify the currently logged in user in order to store the filename that's being uploaded associated with the currently logged in user into my db.

In my logs I'm getting this error:  `local.ERROR: Call to a member function photos()` which means `auth()->user()` is the problem but I just can't see how.  I've tried too many ways to list here in terms of trying to rectify this problem.  What am I doing wrong?

I'll list some things I've tried:

in the `if()` condition inside FileUploadController - `if(auth()->user())`, `if(Auth::guard(api)->check())`, `if(Auth::check())`.

Here's my FileUploadController code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FileUploadController extends Controller {
    public function uploadTest(Request $request) {
        if($request->bearerToken()) {
            auth()->user()->photos()->create([
                'file_path' => $request->file('fileToUpload')->getClientOriginalExtension()
            ]);
            return "file uploaded";
        }
        return "failed uploading";
    }
}
```

Here's my User model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function photos() {
        return $this->hasMany(Photo::class);
    }
}
```

Here's my Photo model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Photo extends Model
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Here's code for logging in the user inside my AuthController:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'remember_me' => 'boolean'
    ]);
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized'
        ], 401);
    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    if ($request->remember_me)
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    $token->save();
    $request->session()->put("user", $user);
    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
            $tokenResult->token->expires_at
        )->toDateTimeString(),
        $user
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I see you are using Passport. But what are you not using the standard passport rolling, like this: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript Using Passport this way there is no need to create your own login logic like you do. You are creating personal access tokens in every login, that is really not a correct way to use OAuth

Comment: @MaartenVeerman are you referring to `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class`?

Comment: Yes indeed. I have a site with a separate Vue frontend. I have the `CreateFreshApiToken` activated, all calls to the api from the frontend use a Bearer token, but there was hardly any coding I had to do to get it all working. By using this option, Laravel will create a fresh token for you.

Comment: @MaartenVeerman ah ok I gotcha.  Is it ok if you send me a snippet for me to see or if you can show me how it should be written in my current code?  I'd greatly appreciate it :)